# How to make a JWT token refreshable in plugin AAM in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, jwt, token, refresh

I'm using the AAM plugin (Version 6.5.2) in Wordpress in order to connect users from a node server with JWT tokens.

No problem to use the plugin to authenticate, validate or revocate tokens, but I can't refresh them, because they are... not refreshable... I get a error 405 `Error: Request failed with status code 405` with: `reason: 'JWT token is not refreshable'`

But the possibility seems to exist!

Here is an example of token claim:

```
{
  "iat": 1553820141,
  "iss": "https://aamplugin.com",
  "exp": 1573225283,
  "jti": "b69fc282-2af4-4222-8d81-f405fc6acb8e",
  "userId": 1,
  "revocable": true,
  "refreshable": false
}
```

I would just like to have a `refreshable: true`.

I guess I should use the filter `aam_jwt_claims_filter` but I don't know exactly how...

If you have some ideas...

Thanks!
Raphaël.

Answer (score 2):

For Wordpress advanced users, it will look like basic. But for me, newbie, it wasn't really easy.

I added the following code to the end of the `functions.php` of my theme (so in `httpdocs/wp-includes`):

```
add_filter('aam_jwt_claims_filter', function($claims) {
    $user = get_user_by('ID', $claims['userId']);
    return array_merge($claims, array(
        'refreshable'  => true,
    ));
}, 10, 1);
```

Hope it can help!